# CSS - Limit number of lines or chracters

Tags: html, css

i try to limit number of lines or some other way limit how long is text to not fail my CSS,

i try the way with:

```
#article-container p {
    padding: 0 10px 0 0;
    margin:0;
    display: -webkit-box;
   -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
   -webkit-line-clamp: 3;  
}
```

(this remove my buttons to "read more" below article

I also try the way with set max-height and display:block and overflow hidden but it move other elements (articles) far away.

But just dont know hot to fix it.

Whole code can be find on [FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/u9LWh/)

Answer (score 2):

http://fiddle.jshell.net/TA78y/6/

```
#article-container p {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 168px;
}

#article-container p.more {
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: normal;
    width: auto;
}
```

Comment: Hey mate, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it dont work for me, looks here for website demo: http://funedit.com/andurit/try1/

Comment: It trims the text with the ellipsis. In what way it does not work for you?

Comment: if u check my link, u can see that it just move everything away from its position in article-container :)

Comment: Decrease the width to width: 168px;

Comment: yea mate that work, and palce thigns on right space again, how can i edit how manz lines to displaz or something because right now i have just 1 line :)

Answer (score 0):

Decrease the with of **#article-container p**

```
#article-container p {
padding: 0 10px 0 0;
margin: 0;
width: 210px; //reduce the width
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: hey man, this going to display just 1 line, if i put width higher number it just move everzthing far away from its position